# No puedo restaurar copia de seguridad de BD sqlite

Tags: android, base-de-datos, android-sqlite

Hola he creado un apartado en mi app para realizar una copia de seguridad de una de las bases de datos importante de la app.
La cuestión es que mi codigo solo crea una base de datos .sqlite pero resulta que automáticamente se generan 2 archivos más .sqlite-wal y .sqlite-shm.
Cuando consulto la base de datos con la extensión .sqlite para ver los campos guardados en ella me muestra un mensaje de error y no me deja mostrarla, en cambio cuando muestro la .sqlite-shm todos los datos están ahí. ¿por que se han generado estos archivos extras, de que archivos tengo que realizar el backup para cuando restaure los datos vuelvan a aparecer correctamente?
Además os paso el codigo porque al realizar el restore no rescata ningún dato del archivo .sqlite.

```
private void importarDB() {
    try {
        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
        if (sd.canWrite()) {
            String currentDBPath = "//data//" + getPackageName()
                    + "//databases//" + "DBnotas" + EquipoJuntoLayout + ".sqlite";
            String backupDBPath = Archivo + EquipoJuntoLayout+".sqlite"; // From SD directory.
            File backupDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
            File currentDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

            FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
            FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
            dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
            src.close();
            dst.close();
            ToastPersonalizado miToast = new ToastPersonalizado(this, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            miToast.show("Restore realizado con éxito");

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

        ToastPersonalizado miToast = new ToastPersonalizado(this, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        miToast.show("El Restore ha fallado");

    }
    PasarDatosMeses();
}

private void exportarDB() {
    try {
        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

        if (sd.canWrite()) {
            String currentDBPath = "//data//" + getPackageName()
                    + "//databases//" + "DBnotas" + EquipoJuntoLayout + ".sqlite";
            String backupDBPath = Archivo + EquipoJuntoLayout+".sqlite";
            File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
            File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

            FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
            FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
            dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
            src.close();
            dst.close();
            ToastPersonalizado miToast = new ToastPersonalizado(this, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            miToast.show("Backup realizado con éxito");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

        ToastPersonalizado miToast = new ToastPersonalizado(this, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        miToast.show("El Backup ha fallado");

    }
    PasarDatosMeses();
}
```

Espero que me podais ayudar con esta duda, si necesitais alguna aclaracion más, por favor decidlo. No se si me habré expresado con claridad.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Cuando realices preguntas, especifica que mensaje de error se muestra, eso ayudará a la comunidad a tener más información sobre como solucionar el problema. saludos.

Comment: Ya he rehecho la pregunta. No da ningún fallo, eso era otra prueba que hice. En realidad no restaura nada del archivo del backup.